# Find the value of the expression involving $e$

Tags: real-analysis, factorial

> Find the value of the expression $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{(2n-2)!}$$

I was doing a problem in which I got this expression as a sub problem.

I donated my brain for over $2$ hours to this question but in vain. I also saw some calculators, but they are solving it with the help of hyperbolic trigonometry which I don't know yet.

I only know expansion of $e$. The original question was

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^3((2n)!+(2n-1)(n!))}{((2n)!)(n!)}$$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$4n^2=(2n-2)(2n-3)+5(2n-2)+4$ and for $n=1,$ this reduces to $4=0+5\cdot0+4,$ hence
$$4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{(2n-2)!}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{(2n-4)!}+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac5{(2n-3)!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac4{(2n-2)!}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1+4}{(2k)!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac5{(2k+1)!}$$
$$=5\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}=5e.$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{(2n-2)!}=\frac{5e}4.$$

Comment: How did you think of such an expression$?$

Comment: It is a usual trick, in order to simplify $\frac{P(m)}{m!}$ were $P$ is a polynomial of degree $d,$ to express the numerator as a linear combination of $m(m-1)\dots(m-d+1),$ $m(m-1)\dots(m-d+2),$ $\dots,$ $m(m-1),$ $m,$ $1.$ And it is always possible because these $d+1$ polynomials in $m$ form a basis of the polynomials of degree $\le d.$

Comment: And can you pls elaborate the shifting of series that you did...and how is the last expression equivalent to $e$$?$

Comment: The first and third series have a factorial of an even number at the denominator, and the first even number for each of them is $0,$ whence the $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1+4}{(2k)!}.$ The second series is treated similarly. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}=e$ is the expansion you said you know.

Comment: To the initial downvoter: can you please explain how you would like me to improve my answer?

Comment: I'm just spitballing here, but perhaps the downvoter thought you got $5e$ as your final answer, rather than the correct $\frac{5e}{4}$? After all, you never explicitly state that the closed form of the series is $\frac{5e}{4}$, and that factor of $4$ at the beginning of your chain of equalities is easy to overlook.

Comment: @C-RAM thank you for this advice!

Answer (score 3):

**Little introduction to hyperbolic geometry :**

Let $\operatorname{ch}(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$ and $\operatorname{sh}(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$. Using the Taylor expansion of $\exp$, namely $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ we get that

$$ \operatorname{ch}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} \text{ and } \operatorname{sh}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $$

**Back to the question :**

On the one hand,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2n(2n-1)}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-2)!}=\operatorname{ch}(1) $$
on the other hand,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2n(2n-1)}{(2n)!}=4\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n^2}{(2n)!}-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)!}=4\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n^2}{(2n)!}-\operatorname{sh}(1) $$
thus
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n^2}{(2n)!}=\frac{\operatorname{ch}(1)+\operatorname{sh}(1)}{4}=\frac{e}{4}. $$
This means that
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n^2}{(2n)!}+\operatorname{sh}(1)+\operatorname{ch}(1)=\frac{5e}{4}. $$

*Remark :*

I've used hyperbolic trigonometry only to lighten the calculations, but you can of course replace $\operatorname{ch}$ and $\operatorname{sh}$ with their expressions using exponentials.

Comment: Very long time I did not see $\text{sh}$ and/or $\text{ch}$

Comment: Would it be better to replace them with $\operatorname{cosh}$ and $\operatorname{sinh}$ ? (I used the notations I am familiar with)

Comment: May be.. But the problem is that the OP does not know the hyperbolic trigonometry.

Comment: My bad I misread the question. I've added a little section to help the OP understand my answer, thanks for the remark.

Comment: The OP does not need to know hyperbolic geometry. This answer does not use any properties of hyperbolic functions

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(2n-2)!}=\frac{x(e^{\sqrt x}+ e^{-\sqrt x })}2$$

Then

$$x f'(x)=x \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n x^{n-1}}{(2n-2)!}=x \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n x^n}{(2n-2)!}$$

and

$$(x f'(x))'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2 x^{n-1}}{(2n-2)!}$$

Now plug in $x=1$ into $(x f'(x))'=f'(x)+xf''(x)$. This gives us the answer $\frac{5e}4$.

Comment: Okay, thanks, of course.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't mind, really  :-)